# hashcat specify number of characters

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, macos, hashcat

I am trying to figure out a macOS hash 10.8+ and I happen to know that it uses `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, is 6-8 characters, and almost certainly random. Currently, it spits out an error regarding hash length being too long, and I do not have any idea how to specify custom charsets or lengths. Someone help.

---

Here is the hash if helpful.

```
$ml$34129$41de87617daa59bec6ac23618384845f6b799bff8cc2ee5197d1499482fe9bac$c8f0c4a0ab9296c352357fed33cc4a9bccf89d8a3a280f2157c18996957dc1894ec18ec61b2ac0e5ddb7977f85f1d95ce338783817b7feebb062406cd47b89500f35806c47dcbefd0b832890c833d01e9472a5a2d64b46bdae1d265968a983fce15e84d6409ae527992224594d27cd430d24dccac851be60d64c75b1353b7f3c
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let me break down, what you want and what the equivalent hashcat options are.

**Hash-Type**

You want to crack a OSX v10.8+ hash, which according to the hashcat example hashes page (https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) is type "7100", so: `-m 7100`.
Specifying the correct hash type should also get rid of the "incorrect length" error.

**Attack-Type**

You want to do a brute force attack against the hash but not with a dictionary of common words but all possible values. That is hashcat attack mode 3 - a mask attack (https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack). So you need to specify `-a 3`.

**Characters**

The following built-in character sets exist:

```
?l = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
?u = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
?d = 0123456789
?h = 0123456789abcdef
?H = 0123456789ABCDEF
?s = «space»!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
?a = ?l?u?d?s
?b = 0x00 - 0xff
```

Your password consists of uppercase letters (`?u`), lowercase letters (`?l`) and digits (`?d`). You can use the built-in hashcat functionality to combine them to a so called custom charset by specifying the charset 1 (`-1`) as `-1?u?l?d`. To specify a mask for passwords with up to eight characters, repeat the specifier eight times `?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1`.

**Length**

You say you password has between six and eight characters. You can tell hashcat to use your all possible combinations from the custom charset that you specified and increment its length up until the length of your mask by using the `--increment` option (https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack#password_length_increment). To tell hashcat to start with a mimimum length of 6, use `--increment-min 6`.

**Full Command**

That gives the following command:
`hashcat -m7100 file_with_hash.txt -a3 -1?l?u?d ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1 --increment --increment-min 6`

Trying all six-character options on two consumer-grade graphic cards, will take 56 days. All seven and eight character passwords will take significantly longer so you might want to reduce the amount of randomness.

Maybe you know, that the password starts with `Mark`. The mask would be `Mark?1?1?1?1`.

Maybe you know it start with an uppercase letter and ends with three digits: `?u?1?1?1?1?d?d?d`.

Please see the hashcat wiki and other questions here for more options.